# Hierarchical management of data packets in Java

Tags: java, networking, packet

I'm working on a Java 2d multiplayer game project. I have an abstract Entity class. The LivingEntity and Bullet classes extend Entity. Player extends LivingEntity and so on. I have a class hierarchy.

For communication with clients, I use packets as simple entity data objects. The EntityAddPacket object contains basic information generally for each entity: uuid, position x, y. LivingEntityAddPacket extends EntityAddPacket with new information such as health and maximum health. These are just examples of selected.
Some packets are sent to clients frequently (20 times per second for an entity, such as a location update) and multiple times. I decided to store objects of such packets in the fields of the Entity class and modify their data in case of changes in the data of the entity itself. Then the data is sent to clients. This improves performance compared to creating a new packet each time.

However, there was a problem. I don't know how to manage these packets in a good way inside the entity hierarchy. The Entity class contains general packets, but the extension classes require more specific data to be sent, as in the case of entities requiring health specified above. Entity should still update its data managed in this class, while extending classes should add their data to the information from Entity.

Suppose Entity has a field of type EntityAddPacket. I can easily modify this data from Entity, but the problem comes when another class should update their information. I am thinking about possible solutions. Entity should update data common to everyone and other classes data specific to them only. I was thinking about using generics, but I don't have idea for this. Is this a good approach? If not, how else can it be done?

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example how you do it currently?  
In Java you can call the function of the parent class with `super`, i.e.  

void process(Data data) {  
  super.process(data);  
  //do your own stuff  
}